# How do I write in Flutter a card widget with the ability to get images as input?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I wrote just a widget with the ability to display a picture and text on top of it. I want to change the widget so that it is a template in which I send the text and image I need, and it displays it, but now there is one and the same image in the entire application. How can I make it possible to send an image as input to `buildImageCard();`

Home page with widget:

```
import 'package:project_alpha/widgets/ImageCard.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      // gridDelegate:
      //     SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      children: [
        buildImageCard(),
        buildImageCard(),
        buildImageCard(),
        buildImageCard(),
        buildImageCard(),
        buildImageCard(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Widget:

```
Widget buildImageCard() => Card(
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              Ink.image(
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/screen.png'),
                height: 240,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 30,
                right: 16,
                left: 16,
                child: Text(
                  'Interesting fact!',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 24,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `AssetImage` you just need the path to the Image. You can pass that path as a `String` to the builder function like any other parameter.

```
Widget buildImageCard(String imagePath) => Card(
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              Ink.image(
                image: AssetImage(imagePath),
                height: 240,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 30,
                right: 16,
                left: 16,
                child: Text(
                  'Interesting fact!',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 24,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );




class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      // gridDelegate:
      //     SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      children: [
        buildImageCard('assets/images/screen.png'),
        buildImageCard('assets/images/screen2.png'),
        buildImageCard('assets/images/screen3.png'),
        buildImageCard('assets/images/screen4.png'),
        buildImageCard('assets/images/screen5.png'),
        buildImageCard('assets/images/screen6.png'),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise you to avoid the creation of methods returning Widgets, consider creating a whole widget extending Stateless or Stateful instead, which is much more efficient.

To solve your problem, this is one of the solutions

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ImageCard extends StatelessWidget {

  final String fact;
  final AssetImage image;

  const ImageCard(this.fact, this.image);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              Ink.image(
                image: image,
                height: 240,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 30,
                right: 16,
                left: 16,
                child: Text(
                  fact,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 24,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can instantiate this widget by calling the following method

```
ImageCard("Your fact", AssetImage("assets/images/image.png"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Widget buildImageCard({String title, String imageAssetName,}) => Card( // CHANGED HERE
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
  ),
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Stack(
        children: [
          Ink.image(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/$imageAssetName.png'),   // CHANGED HERE
            height: 240,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 30,
            right: 16,
            left: 16,
            child: Text(
              title,                    // CHANGED HERE
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 24,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Pass any other configurations using this concept.